# python 3.9 x64 ctypes pass char pointer by reference (char**) OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, python-3.x, char, pointer-to-pointer, byref

First of all
This works perfectly in x32 python, but fails in x64 python with the following error

```
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I got a `hello.dll` written in C++ which exports the following function

```
int __stdcall GetMessage(char **pMsgContainer)
{
    if (!pMsgContainer) return -1;
    if (*pMsgContainer) return -2;
    *pMsgContainer = NULL;
    
    char* msg = "Hello world!";
    
    size_t nLen = strlen(msg);
    *pMsgContainer = new char[nLen + 1];
    strncpy((*pMsgContainer), msg, nLen);
    (*pMsgContainer)[nLen] = 0;
    
    return 0;
}
```

And I call it from Python 3.9 using the following code

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"D:\path-to\hello.dll")
GetMessage = dll.GetMessage

GetMessage.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)]
GetMessage.restype = ctypes.c_int

pBuf = ctypes.c_char_p()
res = GetMessage(ctypes.byref(pBuf))

if (res == 0) :
    print ("Message:", pBuf.value)
else :
    print ("Error:", res)
```

I have compiled two versions of the dll (32 and 64 bit), and tested both of them using a test program in c++, and can confirm both of them work as expected.

Below is C++ code to run it, and I confirm it works perfectly for both 32 and 64 bit dll versions

```
char *pBuf = NULL;
int res = GetMessage(&pBuf);
```

As I stated earlier, this works perfectly with 32 bit python, but fails to work in 64 bit python

I've spent two days on this matter and already checked all the related questions on stackoverflow

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: `if (*pMsgContainer) return -2;` you're de-referencing an unitialized pointer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre how do I initialize the pointer in python?

I've added a C++ code snipped to to show how I call it from C++ console executable

Comment: @LPVOID `pBuf` is initialised to a null pointer in Python. Also I could compile and run this fine in Python 3.6. Try testing in C++ with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` instead of implicit linking

Comment: @Artyer did you compile the dll x64?

Comment: @LPVOID yes (`static_assert(sizeof(void*) == 8)` passed so I'm sure). Also there only a few things using pointers: `*pMsgContainer = ...`, `strlen(msg)`, `new char[nLen + 1]`, `strncpy(new char[nLen + 1], ...)` and `(new char[nLen + 1])[nLen] = 0`. Try and see exactly which pointer is leading to the access violation. Also you can check that python is also 64 bit with `ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_char_p) == 8`